# Can't properly connect to a specific WiFi network

Tags: dns, connection, ping, ubuntu-18.04

I just tried to connect to internet using my home WiFi network and didn't manage. I use Ubuntu 18.04.

I am able to connect using hotspot or any other network, but not this one from home. Also it works fine with Windows. I tried with the Ethernet cable as well and didn't work.

I mention I have Atheros QCA9565 .

I tried:
`ping 8.8.8.8` and this was successful.

Then:
`ping google.com` and got this error message: **name or service unknown**.

Therefore I added:
`nameserver 8.8.8.8` in */etc/resolv.conf* file and made this persistent after noticing it is reinitialised at reboot: https://www.tecmint.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-debian/
Sometimes I can do `ping google.com` but the time is badly increasing, so it's super slow.
And when I can't connect at all, `ping google.com` has the same error message.

I mention that I tried to turn off DNS automatic from IPv4 tab from WiFi network settings and the connection persisted for 10 seconds or so: https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/ubuntu-set-dns-server/

Might it be a hardware problem or what should I try next?

Comment: So ping on google.com has times that keep increasing AFTER the DNS name resolution, but ping on 8.8.8.8 does not?

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not be the issue, I recently had problems with the built-in Wifi on my computer's motherboard.  I could access some sites at a good speed while others were unreachable. I tried several things I found online but nothing helped.  I spent 30 USD on Amazon for a generic AC1200 PCIe Adapter and all the problems/issues have been resolved.  Apparently, something was off with the card that was originally part of the computer.

I was told this should not have made some websites not load but the new card has none of the issues at all.